# Custom listview CheckableRelativeLayout is setChecked(false) on repaint

Tags: android, listview

I have made a class CheckableRelativeLayout that extends RelativeLayout and implements Checkable. It is a custom listview that has the ability to check listitems, in my case radio buttons.

I override the setChecked-method and I find that it gets called with a false value every time my view is repainted.

What I want to do is call setChecked(true); on the first item in my list but when the view is repainted my call makes no difference.