# setChecked(false) called for some reason

Tags: android, adapter

I have current adapter:

```
public class FolderImagesAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private List<String> mData;
    private Context mContext;

    public FolderImagesAdapter(Context context, List<String> data) {
        mContext = context;
        mData = data;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(convertView == null) {
            convertView = new FolderImageItemView(mContext);
        }
        ((FolderImageItemView)convertView).setData(mData.get(position));

        return convertView;
    }

    public void setData(List<String> data) {
        mData = data;
    }
}
```

And this is my View class :

```
public class FolderImageItemView extends FrameLayout implements Checkable{

private ImageView mThumbnail;
private View mSelection;

private String mPath;
private boolean mChecked;
private SelectedImagesHolder mHolder;

public FolderImageItemView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    inflate(getContext(), R.layout.item_view_folder_image, this);
    mThumbnail = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv_thumb);
    mSelection = findViewById(R.id.selection);
}

public void setData(String thumbPath){
    mPath = thumbPath;
    mHolder = SelectedImagesHolder.getInstance();
    Utils.toLog(mHolder.getmSelectedImages().toArray());
    Glide.with(getContext()).load(thumbPath).into(mThumbnail);
    if(mHolder.getmSelectedImages().contains(thumbPath)) {
        setChecked(true);
    }
}

@Override
public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
    mChecked = checked;
    if(mChecked) {
        mSelection.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        if(!mHolder.getmSelectedImages().contains(mPath)) {
            mHolder.addImage(mPath);
        }
    } else {
        mSelection.setVisibility(GONE);
        //mHolder.removeImage(mPath);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean isChecked() {
    return mChecked;
}

@Override
public void toggle() {
    setChecked(!mChecked);
}

@Override
public boolean performClick() {
    toggle();
    return super.performClick();
}
```

}

The thing is that `setData` method should check items, that holder already have(holder is a singletone). **I have data in singletone, and setChecked(true) is working, but somewhere after its setChecked(false) get called for all items and all of them become unselected**.

I want to know what is problem here, and how can I solve it. I've searched for this and find some post which explains that `getView` is calling setChecked(false), but `setData` method is called there and it should work.

Comment: I suggest you create an exception on setChecked and log it, so you can see from where it's being called: `Log.w(TAG, "setChecked", new Throwable());`

Comment: probably the same issue as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7335457/custom-listview-checkablerelativelayout-is-setcheckedfalse-on-repaint although there also is no anwer yet

Comment: Why are you implementing `Checkable`? Without that you will know for sure your methods are only called by your code.

Comment: @weston Because i need custom logic and UI behaviour for items with multiple choice

Comment: I mean what would break when you remove `implements Checkable` (and `@Override`s )because that is what's calling your methods.

Comment: @weston, everything,  no logic will work =)

Comment: Eh? the code you have shown doesn't rely on the `Checkable` interface. (I don't mean remove the overridden methods, I mean remove `@Override`)

Comment: @weston if i remove it, how i suppose to get setChecked triggering on selecting item?

Comment: I figured you've wired that manually in `performClick` which is calling `toggle` which is calling `setChecked`

Answer (score 0):

So, the final solution is not great, but it's working. First of all few things :

1. `performClick` override wasn't triggering for some reason, but `setOnClickListener(this)` and `toggle` there worked(i guess it has something to do with handling clicks in ListView and such ViewGroups as it.
2. If i remove implement for Checkable it will not work, because i need this setChecked to be triggered

My solution is to simply create `boolean mIsFromClick` and set it to true only if click happened and do stuff only if this field is set to true, so, eventually it all looks like this :

```
public class FolderImageItemView extends FrameLayout implements Checkable, OnClickListener {

    private ImageView mThumbnail;
    private View mSelection;

    private String mPath;
    private boolean mChecked;
    private boolean mIsFromClicked = false;
    private SelectedImagesHolder mHolder;

    public FolderImageItemView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setOnClickListener(this);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        inflate(getContext(), R.layout.item_view_folder_image, this);
        mThumbnail = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv_thumb);
        mSelection = findViewById(R.id.selection);
    }

    public void setData(String thumbPath){
        mPath = thumbPath;
        mHolder = SelectedImagesHolder.getInstance();
        Utils.toLog(mHolder.getmSelectedImages().toArray());
        Glide.with(getContext()).load(thumbPath).into(mThumbnail);
        if(mHolder.getmSelectedImages().contains(mPath)) {
            mIsFromClicked = true;
            setChecked(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
        //Utils.toLog(new Throwable());
        if(mIsFromClicked) {
            mChecked = checked;
            if (mChecked) {
                mSelection.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                if (!mHolder.getmSelectedImages().contains(mPath)) {
                    mHolder.addImage(mPath);
                }
            } else {
                mSelection.setVisibility(GONE);
                mHolder.removeImage(mPath);
            }
            mIsFromClicked = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChecked() {
        return mChecked;
    }

    @Override
    public void toggle() {
        mIsFromClicked = true;
        setChecked(!mChecked);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Utils.toLog("click performed");
        toggle();
    }
}
```

Better approaches should be post in answers, Thanks to all.